# Why is this vim regex so expensive: s/\n/\\n/g

Tags: regex, vim, newline

Attempting this on a sufficiently large file (say 80,000+ lines and about 500k+) will crash things or stall eventually both on my server and on my local Mac.

I've tried this at the command line as well, with the same result:

```
vim -es -c '%s/\n/\\n/g' -c wq $file
```

Also, the problem appears to be with the selection (`\n`) and not the replacement (`\\n`).

For my larger files I can of course `split` them and `cat` them back when finished, but the split points cannot be arbitrary in my case and must be adjusted manually for each and every split.

I appreciate that there are other ways to do this -- sed, etc. -- but I have similar and additional problems there, and I would like to be able to do this with vim.

Comment: My best guess (without analyzing the vim or regex source code): substituting newlines changes the number of lines. Maybe some of the code has an O(n^2) time or memory complexity (undo buffer?). With 80.000+ that is a big n^2. Can you monitor the memory usage of the vim process on your server (top, vmstat)?

Comment: OK I'm moving my answer here: `%s/$/\\n/g` works fine and pretty fast though on a 56K line/16MB file.

Comment: @jingx Follow that with a `%j!` and you'll get the same effect as OP, but probably way faster

Comment: I get a out of memory when trying `80000itest<enter><esc>:%s/\n/\\n/g` but I have a 32-bit version of gvim. Are you using a 32-bit version or 64-bit version?

Comment: I created a simple ~500KB file with a simple script. No new line characters, just a single line. Then I tried to load the file with vim. I had to kill it :). So I guess It is the 'big line' and not the replacement itself.

Another way to confirm this is to replace `\n` by `\n\n`. If it is fast, then the problem is the 'big line' issue.

Comment: vim is definitely not the right tool for this. It's not designed to edit text files with over five hundred thousand characters per line, which is what the result of that replacement will be.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding my comment as an answer:

Text editors usually don't like 'gigantic' lines (which is what you'll get with that replacement).

To test that if this is is due because of the 'big line' and not the substitution itself I did this test:

I created a simple ~500KB file with a script. No new line characters, just a single line. Then I tried to load the file with vim. Result? I had to kill it :-).

However, if on the same script I write some new lines every now and then, I have no problems opening the file.

Also, one thing you could try is the following: on vim, replace `\n` by `\n\n` if it is fast, then this should also confirm the 'big line' issue.